# Material stepper with angular 6 does not work [method for animation not found in browser.js]

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and I added the material components to my project following the steps in this [Guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started). But when I use the stepper component in my code I get the following exception in the console:

```
NewReqComponent.html:16 ERROR TypeError: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function
at browser.js:844
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at browser.js:843
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor._validateStyleAst (browser.js:840)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitStyle (browser.js:780)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.push../node_modules/@angular/animations/fesm5/browser.js.AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitState (browser.js:678)
at browser.js:657
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at browser.js:655
```

I used the component like this:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
  <mat-step label="step1">step1</mat-step>
  <mat-step label="step2">step2</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

and the app.module.ts:

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  BrowserAnimationsModule,
  RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes) ,
  FormsModule, HttpClientModule ,
  FormWizardModule ,
  ArchwizardModule,
  MatStepperModule
],
```

Comment: In your package.json, try changing @angular/animations to version 6.0.5, then run npm install.

Comment: I tried that, its not work and I still got the same error

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-g6ymwe I hope this demo helps

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990209/angular-material-stepper-not-working-on-stackblitz/50990428#50990428

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material Stepper not working on StackBlitz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50990209/angular-material-stepper-not-working-on-stackblitz)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that there is a mismatch between the angular version and the material version.
Please make sure to update the angular to the latest.

try to set it to 6.0.6 version and I think it will works fine.

Comment: If it does not work with 6.0.6 you can try with 6.0.5 in my case it worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

you are required to upgrade Angular.json. Run these commands and that's it.

```
$ ng update @angular/cli
$ ng update @angular/core
$ ng update @angular/material
```

Answer (score 0):

npm install @angular/animations@6.0.1 --save --save-exact

Edit: Nevermind, found out that the verision of Ionic I use still uses Angular 6, which means the animation module need to match the angular core module’s version number. If your core module is version 6.0.1, you need to install @angular/animations@6.0.1 with npm