# Angular Material Stepper not working on StackBlitz

Tags: angular, angular-material, stackblitz

I'm working on an idea to create a quiz primarily using [the Angular Material Stepper](https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview). I have the concept working on my localhost but I'd like to put it on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) so I can easily share the concept with coworkers with just a link.

I've followed all the steps

> npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
>
> npm install --save @angular/animations

[image: NPM Packages]

> Import the NgModule for each component you want to use:

[image: Module Imports]

> Include a theme

[image: Theme Import]

> Gesture Support

[image: Gesture Support]

And I'm still seeing a blank screen when I try to use

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

My full source can be [viewed here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dzklvm)

What exactly am I doing wrong? This works on my local machine.

Comment: If you have the project on GitHub, you can do the following: [`stackblitz.com/github/{GH_USERNAME}/{REPO_NAME}`](https://blog.angular.io/run-angular-cli-repos-directly-in-your-browser-41332fd80901) - might work

Comment: Wow that's great. But I'd still like to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Possibly [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11875). Looks like a bug with this version of the stepper

Comment: update npm packages fixes it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fvsdnq Seems like the cause was angular 6.0.0, recent version 6.0.6 resolves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that updating your dependencies solves the issue.

In your screenshot of the dependencies, there's a refresh icon and when clicked, updates your dependencies.

[Updated demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xm2ytq)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy.